# How to configure generic logging API on AWS API to push event logs to AWS CloudWatch

Tags: aws-api-gateway

Goal: I have an Angular 5 client that I wish to centralise logging to AWS CloudWatch so that I can view all logs (from the web client, API, lambdas, DynamoDB) in one place.
Solution considered: 
(1) Create an API on the AWS Api Gateway with the CloudWatch Logs (AWS Service)
(2) Angular 5 client will post all logging to this API.

Problem:
I am having difficulty configuring the AWS Api Gateway correctly.  The documentation on this is particularly sparse.  I have created a simple test API with the following configuration.
[Basic API configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1m8Zn.png)

This is a POST method on the API. The TestAPIRole has permission to PutEventLogs to CloudWatch.

I ran a test with the following data:

[Test message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RihDk.png)

And I get the following response:
[Response from test message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRF0.png)

I think I haven't configure the API right but I am not sure what else to try.  Has anyone tried to configure AWS API Gateway to post log events to Cloudwatch?

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone tried to configure AWS API Gateway to post log events to Cloudwatch?

We have an error-logger API (API Gateway + Lambda) we use at work. At the minimum, it's just a simple POST endpoint that receives what the frontend (ours is in React) error handler sends. The Lambda simply writes to CloudWatch and we aggregate them through ElasticSearch.

Comment: How do you authenticate the API? Does it happen using the consumer's credentials or API is open? or how else? Struggling with this

Comment: It used the consumer's credentials just like any other backend endpoint.